# Getting back 0 result from LINQ through Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create a simple Add User page that goes through a Web Service, Linq and Stored Procedure. I have set the result of my stored procedure to return as a boolean. The thing is it is always coming back as false. And I cannot see where the error lies as it does not return  any 'error' message.

I think there is nothing wrong with my main .aspx page as it seems to pass through the data through to the Web Service. So I will only post the rest of the code:

WebService.cs:

```
   public bool AddUser(string Name, int Contact, string Email, string Password, bool Admin, string ImageURL)
{
    bool result = false;

        using (DataClassesDataContext dbcontext = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var query = dbcontext.CreateUser(Name, Contact, Email, Password, Admin, ImageURL); //as far as I can see, the values get passed through these parameters. But the query returns false.
            result = Convert.ToBoolean(query);
        }

    return result;
}
```

DataContext.designer.cs:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.CreateUser")]
public int CreateUser([global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Name", DbType="VarChar(50)")] string name, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ContactNo", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> contactNo, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Email", DbType="VarChar(50)")] string email, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Password", DbType="VarChar(50)")] string password, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="Admin", DbType="Bit")] System.Nullable<bool> admin, [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ImageURL", DbType="NVarChar(200)")] string imageURL)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), name, contactNo, email, password, admin, imageURL);
    return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Stored Procedure CreateUser:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser
@Name varchar(50),
@ContactNo int,
@Email varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@Admin bit,
@ImageURL nvarchar(200)
AS
INSERT INTO Users
([Name], ContactNo, Email, Password, Admin, ImageURL)
VALUES
(@Name, @ContactNo, @Email, @Password, @Admin, @ImageURL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) specifies:

> Unless documented otherwise, all system stored procedures return a value of 0. This indicates success and a nonzero value indicates failure.

If you want to explicitly return `true` from your stored procedure use this code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser @Name      VARCHAR(50),
                               @ContactNo INT,
                               @Email     VARCHAR(50),
                               @Password  VARCHAR(50),
                               @Admin     BIT,
                               @ImageURL  NVARCHAR(200)
AS
    INSERT INTO Users
                ([Name],
                 ContactNo,
                 Email,
                 Password,
                 Admin,
                 ImageURL)
    VALUES      (@Name,
                 @ContactNo,
                 @Email,
                 @Password,
                 @Admin,
                 @ImageURL)

    RETURN 1
```

**UPDATE**

The approach above is not foolproof - if the insert fails the procedure won't return an error status code but will throw an exception which will prevent your method from returning the success indicator (`false`). A far better approach would be to not return any status codes from your stored procedure and handle eventual exceptions in code.

```
public bool AddUser(string Name, int Contact, string Email, string Password, bool Admin, string ImageURL)
{
    using (DataClassesDataContext dbcontext = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            var query = dbcontext.CreateUser(Name, Contact, Email, Password, Admin, ImageURL); 
            // If the execution got here then the insert succeeded
            // and you can return 'success' to caller
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Log the exception
            // If the execution got here it means that the insert failed and 
            // an exception was thrown (in other words the execution didn't get to 
            // the <return true;> instruction.
            // In this case return 'fail' to caller.
            return false;
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I see, so I should just check for Null (if there is an error) and 0 (or if I add RETURN 1) for a successful update?